# Conditional Parameters in Spring Boot Restful Service

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, swagger

I have built a RESTful service using Spring Boot. It is annotated using Swagger.

There are a number of instances where there is an either-or choice on the request coming through to the service. What we have done up to now is to create multiple endpoints to accommodate this but it's not effective seeing as 90% of the request is the same.

Is there a way to annotate an either-or condition on the request object? If not, what other options could I explore to achieve this?

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "optionalOne", "optionalTwo" })
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Test {

@ApiModelProperty(value = "An optional parameter that should be present only 
when my dependent parameter is not set",
        required = true)
@JsonProperty
private String optionalOne;

@ApiModelProperty(value = "An optional parameter that should be present only when my dependent parameter is not set",
        required = true)
@JsonProperty
private String optionalTwo;
}
```

Using the above as an example, if the "optionalOne" property is set then I expect "optionalTwo" to be null/empty. And vice versa too.

Is there a way to cater for this scenario without the use of custom validators?

Thanks

Comment: If your property is NOT required and there are cases where you expect it to be null, why have you set required = true and why do you validate for @ NotNull?

Comment: How could it be `@NotNull` if it's optional? Using `@NotNull` is wrong here.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. The @ NotNull is not meant to be there as you have indeed indicated. I've cleaned up the snippet. The question still remains. Any ideas?